# Python how to use a value from another function and bind the function to a Tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, ttkwidgets

I'm new to programming in general. I have made a simple tool that converts images into WebP format.

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Button
# Set up window and configure the sizes
window = Tk()
window.title('Webp Converter')
window.geometry('300x150')
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
window.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 1.5)
icon = PhotoImage(file="uhggg-16.png")
window.iconphoto(False, icon)
# Define functions
def uploadConvert():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    filename = filepath.split('.')[0]
    image = Image.open(filepath)
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    if image.size[0] > 700 or image.size[1] > 700:
        image.thumbnail(size=((700, 700)))
    image.save(f'{filename}.webp', 'webp')
# Labels and fields
lbl = Label(window, text='Select your image to convert:')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)
btn_upload = Button(text='Upload and convert', command=uploadConvert)
btn_upload.grid(column=0, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine here.

I wanted to add a feature that display the selected image's size (width x height) in 2 input fields and you can change width and height, width/height ratio stays the same, or you can leave it as it is and proceed webp conversion.
I know I will need an extra button and 2 input fields to do that. But I don't know what exactly to do.

I tried to split the uploadConvert() function into 2 functions: upload() and convert(). upload() opens the image and get the image name, convert(filename, image) receives 2 parameters from upload() and convert the image. upload() and convert() will be bind to 2 separate ttk buttons.

The first issue I encountered is that convert() won't get the objects from upload() and also I don't know how exactly I should bind a function to button with multiple params using "command=" for ttk buttons.

I have also tried to add 2 Entry as width and height display/input fields..

Edited Code：

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import PhotoImage, Entry
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Button
# Set up window and configure the sizes
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('WEBPER')
window.geometry('230x300')
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
window.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 1.5)
icon = PhotoImage(file="uhggg-16.png")
window.iconphoto(False, icon)
# Define functions
def upload():
    global filepath, filename
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    filename = filepath.split('.')[0]
    image = Image.open(filepath)
    wvar.set(image.size[0])
    hvar.set(image.size[1])
    lbl_bot.configure(text='Image uploaded', foreground='#000000')

def convert():
    try:
        wint = int(wvar.get())
        hint = int(hvar.get())
        image = Image.open(filepath)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image.thumbnail(size=((wint, hint)))
        image.save(f'{filename}.webp', 'webp')
        lbl_bot.configure(text='Succesfully converted!', foreground='#4BB543')
    except:
        lbl_bot.configure(text='Upload your image first!', foreground='#FF0000')
# Labels and fields
wvar = tk.StringVar()
wvar.set('0')
hvar = tk.StringVar()
hvar.set('0')
lbl_top = Label(window, text='Select your image to convert:')
lbl_top.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)
lbl_bot = Label(window, text='No image selected', foreground='#000000', background='#D3D3D3')
lbl_bot.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=20, pady=(15,20))
lbl = Label(window, text='Width:')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl = Label(window, text='Height:')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=3)
width = Entry(textvariable=wvar, width=7)
width.grid(column=0, row=2)
height = Entry(textvariable=hvar, width=7)
height.grid(column=0, row=4, pady=(0, 20))
btn_upload = Button(text='Upload', command=upload)
btn_upload.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=(0, 10))
btn_convert = Button(text='Convert', command=convert)
btn_convert.grid(column=0, row=6)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `upload()` has to keep image in `global` variable to access it in `convert()` (if you don't plan to generate new button after loading image)

Comment: if you want to use `command=` with parameters then you can use `lambda` - like `commnad=lambda:convert(image)`,. But `width` and `height` I would get from `Entry` directly inside `def convert()` (not send them as parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filepath and filename are derived from the function upload() which in turn will be used by the function convert(). So declare these two variables as global so that these can be used in other functions as well.

But convert() can use the variables of upload() only if upload() was executed before convert(). Logically, the user is going to upload file and then only will convert. So, naturally upload() will be executed. So this fulfils
our requirement.

But in case if the user clicks convert button without clicking upload button, convert will be executed. But since the variables filepath and filename are not defined, it'll give name error. To resolve this, We use 'try..except..' method to handle error.

By importing messagebox module, user can get popup messages. So, it is coded like: if there is name error, the messagebox will popout asking the user to upload file first.

Now as upload and convert are two different buttons which triggers two different functions viz upload() and convert() respectively, we don't need to worry about binding buttons with two functions.

Since you wanted the user input of width and height, these can be added with Entry  widgets. The user input can be received by Entry_widget.get(). Here width.get and height.get(). As these need to be converted into integers, these will be int(width.get()) and int(height.get(()).

The Entry widget you didn't import. I added that part as well.

Edit:

The following part is the edited code of the previous one. I edited after seeing your comment.

Since you want the scale to be maintained during conversion, the user is just required give the required width alone. So that our code will decide the required height accordingly.(Reqd_height=(actual_height/actual_width)*got_width)

Value error sometime happens when we convert directly from string. (Actually it didn't happen when I ran). when we make got_width=int(float(width)), this won't occur. corrected in the code.

works perfect,

Just take this as a basic concept and be creative in implementing your own ideas.For eg., you can modify like: the program ask the user whether they want to enter required height or required width. If the user selects 'required width', the required height will be calculated like how we have done. If the user selects 'required_height', the program will calculate the 'required_width'.

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Entry
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Button
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

# Define functions
def upload():
    global filepath
    global filename
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    filename = filepath.split('.')[0]
    
def convert():
    
   try:
        got_width = int(float(width.get()))
        image = Image.open(filepath)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        actual_width = image.size[0]
        actual_height = image.size[1]
        if actual_width > got_width:
            reqd_height = (actual_height/actual_width)*got_width
            reqd_height = round(reqd_height,0)
        else: reqd_height = actual_height
        image.thumbnail(size=((got_width, reqd_height)))
        image.save(f'{filename}.webp', 'webp')
    except NameError:
        mb.showinfo('Upload File', 'Upload your file before converting')
        
 

# Set up window and configure the sizes
window = Tk()
window.title('Webp Converter')
window.geometry('300x350')
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')


window.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 1.5)
icon = PhotoImage(file="uhggg-16.png")
window.iconphoto(False, icon)

    
# Labels and fields
wdth = Label(window, text='Required width:')
wdth.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=20)

width = Entry(window)
width.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=20, pady=20)

lbl = Label(window, text='Select your image to convert:')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=20, pady=20)
btn_upload = Button(text='Upload', command=upload)
btn_upload.grid(column=0, row=6)

btn_convert = Button(text='convert', command=convert)
btn_convert.grid(column=0, row=7)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But it gives an error when converting..got_width = int(width.get())
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I want to add values (image width and height) to the two input fields when I click upload. They can be changed, but their ratio stays the same. For example, when I upload an image 100 x 300, and it will display 100 and 300 in the input fields, if I want to change the width to 50, then the height value will automatically be changed to 150.. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I have edited my code inspired by your code. But what I'm trying to do is that I want to change Height value once Width value is changed by user. Just like in photoshop, when you change width, the height automatically changes. Please see my edited code. And thank you again for your patience and time!

Comment: automatic Change in width/height -input field is possible without changing the scale. provided after entering the value.  Bind '<Leave>' with the respective function.

Comment: Could you indicate how to do that? Maybe edit on top of my code if you don't mind?

Comment: @rottenwood, Many don't encourage writing the entire code. So, I'm sharing the screenshot of code. Read step by step. You'll understand, [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/2fDUdeH). Please follow the title-number I've mentioned in the images since 2 and 3 got interchanged while posting the image.

Comment: @rottenwood, 2 pages only. But the number I've mentioned wrongly as 3 instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables across functions, I would suggest to use class as instance variables can be accessed across class methods.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog as fd
from PIL import Image

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Webp Converter")
        self.minsize(300, 150)
        self.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
        self.call("tk", "scaling", 1.5)
        icon = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/webp-logo.png")
        self.iconphoto(False, icon)

        btn_upload = ttk.Button(self, text="Select your image to convert", command=self.upload)
        btn_upload.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="w")

        # panel for conversion (initial hidden)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.width_var = tk.StringVar()
        entry_width = ttk.Entry(self.frame, width=5, textvariable=self.width_var, justify="center")
        entry_width.pack(side="left")
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text=" x ").pack(side="left")
        self.height_var = tk.StringVar()
        entry_height = ttk.Entry(self.frame, width=5, textvariable=self.height_var, justify="center")
        entry_height.pack(side="left")
        btn_convert = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Convert", command=self.convert)
        btn_convert.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        # need to calculate the width or height when "Enter" key is pressed or leave the entry box
        self.event_add("<<Updated>>", "<Return>", "<FocusOut>")
        entry_width.bind("<<Updated>>", self.set_height)
        entry_height.bind("<<Updated>>", self.set_width)

    def upload(self):
        filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
        if filepath:
            self.image_path = filepath
            self.image = Image.open(filepath)
            self.width_var.set(self.image.width)
            self.height_var.set(self.image.height)
            self.frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)

    def convert(self):
        # get the output filename with extension .webp
        output = Path(self.image_path)
        output = output.with_suffix(".webp")
        try:
            # resize the image and save as webp format
            size = int(self.width_var.get()), int(self.height_var.get())
            self.image.resize(size).save(output, "webp")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid size:", self.width_var.get(), self.height_var.get())

    def set_width(self, event):
        try:
            height = int(float(self.height_var.get()))
            self.width_var.set(int(self.image.width*height/self.image.height))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid height:", self.height_var.get())

    def set_height(self, event):
        try:
            width = int(float(self.width_var.get()))
            self.height_var.set(int(self.image.height*width/self.image.width))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid width:", self.width_var.get())

App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks quite complex. I will search and learn how class and everything else works.